# Error: Invalid hook call how can i solve it?

Tags: reactjs

this is the error i received

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

This is my code:

```
const HandleAdd = () => {
  const [reRender, setRerender] = useState(false);
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Add Department',
    text: "Input department name below.",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Save',
    html: generateInputForms({
      strname: '',
      intsequence: ''
    }),

    preConfirm: () => {
      let strname = document.getElementById('strname').value;
      let intsequence = document.getElementById('intsequence').value;
 
      if (!strname) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Department field is required.')
      }
      if (!intsequence) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Sequence field is required.')
      }
      return {
        strname: document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence: document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      let request = {
        strresourcename: "Richard",
        strapplicationcode: "SchoolApp",
        strmodulename: "Department",
        strtablename: "fmDepartments",
        strfieldid: "fmDepartmentsId",
        strname:document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence:document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
      addDepartment(request).then(function(res){
        if (res.status == 200){
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Department',
            text: 'New Department has been added successfully.',
          }).then((res) => {
            setRerender(!reRender);
          })
        }else{
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Oops',
            text: 'Something went wrong.',
          })
        }
      })
          
    }
  })
}
class CustomToolbar extends React.Component {
  
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Add User Initiated...");
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Tooltip title={"Add"}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="small"
              style={{
                textTransform: 'unset',
                outline: 'none',
                marginLeft: 20,
                backgroundColor: '#00B029',
              }}
              onClick={HandleAdd}
              className={classes.button}
              startIcon={<AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} style={{color: '#fff',}} />}
            >
              Add
            </Button>
        </Tooltip>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}

export default withStyles(defaultToolbarStyles, { name: "CustomToolbar" })(CustomToolbar);
```

dependency

```
{
  "name": "@group1/school-template",
  "version": "3.2.1",
  "description": "School Access Management System",
  "author": {
    "github": "https://github.com",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Group1 Team",
      "url": "https://github.com"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": ".",
  "copyright": "Copyright Richard M.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/chartjs": "^2.0.0",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^3.4.0",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.0.0",
    "@coreui/icons-react": "^1.1.0",
    "@coreui/react": "^3.4.6",
    "@coreui/react-chartjs": "^1.1.0",
    "@coreui/utils": "^1.3.1",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars": "^19.2.47",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
    "downshift": "^3.4.8",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "filter-material-ui": "^2.7.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "match-sorter": "^4.2.1",
    "material-ui-filter": "^3.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mui-datatables": "^3.7.7",
    "nanoid": "^3.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.2.0",
    "react-date-range": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dual-listbox": "^2.1.2",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^4.0.3",
    "react-multiselect-checkboxes": "^0.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.0.20",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^4.1.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "auto-changelog": "~2.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:cov": "npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "changelog": "auto-changelog --starting-version 3.0.0 --commit-limit false --hide-credit"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://ncfsolutionsinc.com"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 10",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/*index.js",
      "!src/serviceWorker.js",
      "!src/polyfill.js"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10",
    "npm": ">=6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `useState` in non functional component. You're using it in a method called `HandleAdd`. `HandleAdd` is not a component! You're using classify component. You need to move the  `HandleAdd` into your component and use the class component's own `state` and `setState` :

```
class CustomToolbar extends React.Component {
  state = false;
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.HandleAdd = this.HandleAdd.bind(this);
  }
  HandleAdd = () => {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Add Department',
    text: "Input department name below.",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Save',
    html: generateInputForms({
      strname: '',
      intsequence: ''
    }),

    preConfirm: () => {
      let strname = document.getElementById('strname').value;
      let intsequence = document.getElementById('intsequence').value;
 
      if (!strname) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Department field is required.')
      }
      if (!intsequence) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Sequence field is required.')
      }
      return {
        strname: document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence: document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      let request = {
        strresourcename: "Richard",
        strapplicationcode: "SchoolApp",
        strmodulename: "Department",
        strtablename: "fmDepartments",
        strfieldid: "fmDepartmentsId",
        strname:document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence:document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
      addDepartment(request).then(function(res){
        if (res.status == 200){
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Department',
            text: 'New Department has been added successfully.',
          }).then((res) => {
            this.setState(!this.state);
          })
        }else{
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Oops',
            text: 'Something went wrong.',
          })
        }
      })
          
    }
  })
}


  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Add User Initiated...");
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Tooltip title={"Add"}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="small"
              style={{
                textTransform: 'unset',
                outline: 'none',
                marginLeft: 20,
                backgroundColor: '#00B029',
              }}
              onClick={this.HandleAdd}
              className={classes.button}
              startIcon={<AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} style={{color: '#fff',}} />}
            >
              Add
            </Button>
        </Tooltip>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: yes okay, but how can i solve that?

Comment: @kaito updated. Please check

Comment: Line 108:24:  'HandleAdd' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @kaito Updated. Because I don't have the real code. That was my mistake. you need to use `this` before method call.

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Comment: i got this error though

Comment: In which line do you have this error?

Comment: from this `this.state = false;` and `setState(!this.state);` i declare `setState`

Comment: @kaito Excuse me. I don't have the real code. Let me try that. I will answer.

Comment: Just change `this.state = false;` to `state = false;` and change  `setState(!this.state);` to `this.setState(!this.state);`

Comment: the error is still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237314/discussion-between-majid-m-and-kaito).

Answer (score -1):

You can't use hooks inside the methods. It should be a functional component

here `HandleAdd` is a method, not a component

Comment: How is this different than the answer already provided?