# Cannot call useParams hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, frontend

I am trying to use the useParams() hook in one of my functions in React but it gives the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a 
function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

The React component where I'm trying to call useParams() looks like this

```
const IndividualEvent = () => {
const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
const [event, setEvent] = useState(null);
const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(true);

const Fetchevent = () => {
    const {eventName} = useParams();
    alert(eventName);
}

useEffect(() => {
    Fetchevent();
})

return (
    <div id="individual-event">
        {
            showLoader ? <Loader text='Fetching event details'/> : null
        }
        <Sidebar />
        <div id="event-container" className="page">

        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

What is the error here and how to solve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Invalid hook call how can i solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69267921/error-invalid-hook-call-how-can-i-solve-it)

Comment: Also, [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Answer (score 5):

Remove `useParams` from inside the `Fetchevent` arrow function, react doesn not recognize the arrow function as a react function, put it directly on the top level like the `useState` you have. One of the rules of hooks is that you should not use hooks inside nexted functions, thats where the issue is comming from. Your code should look like this

```
const IndividualEvent = () => {
const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
const [event, setEvent] = useState(null);
const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(true);
const {eventName} = useParams(); // this line was moved here

const Fetchevent = () => {
    alert(eventName);
}

useEffect(() => {
    Fetchevent();
})

return (
    <div id="individual-event">
        {
            showLoader ? <Loader text='Fetching event details'/> : null
        }
        <Sidebar />
        <div id="event-container" className="page">

        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me - it turned out I put the useParams in the wrong place too.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a version of `react-dom` (< 16.8.0) or `react-native` (< 0.59) that doesn’t yet support Hooks.
try run

```
npm ls react-dom
```

or

```
npm ls react
```

in your application folder to check which version you’re using. If you find more than one of them, this might also create problems.
If you see more than one, you can debug this problem by adding some logs and restarting your development server:

```
// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

If it prints `false` then you might have two Reacts and need to figure out why that happened.

[This issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) includes some common reasons encountered by the community.

Comment: This is a wrong answer - clearly the OP is breaking the rules of hooks and tries to call `Fetchevent` inside a `useEffect`, but `Fetchevent`, since it uses a hook inside it, is by definition a hook itself

Comment: ...but in general case it would be good advice. So keep helping other people!